# Can Microsoft AJAX be used for mobile web

Tags: jquery, .net, mobile, microsoft-ajax

The framework is .NET. Since it has Microsoft AJAX, jQuery baked in, can these be leveraged for the mobile web or would it be better to use a JS mobile library instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX alone isn't mobile optimized at all.  Using UpdatePanels on a mobile device would be even slower than on the desktop, for example.

That doesn't count ASP.NET out for mobile development though, of course.  I've had great results mixing ASP.NET with jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)